# (1.16.2) What is the most efficient way to /spreadplayers into a different dimension?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to have all entities that travel to the Nether be instantly teleported back to a random location in the Overworld.

The `/spreadplayers` command is perfect for the random location:

`spreadplayers 0 0 0 45 under 30 false @s`

And I can detect any entity in the nether with a predicate:

```
{
  "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
  "entity": "this",
  "predicate": {
    "location": {
      "dimension": "minecraft:the_nether"
    }
  }
}
```

Like so: `spreadplayers 0 0 0 45 under 30 false @e[predicate=namespace:in_nether]`

Unfortunately, this command spreads all entities randomly around 0x 0z in the Nether, not the Overworld.

---

I then tried:

`execute in minecraft:overworld run spreadplayers 0 0 0 45 under 30 false @e[predicate=namespace:in_nether]`

The result was the same.

---

I decided to do some testing, so I replaced the first command's `/spreadplayers` with `/tp`:

`tp @e[predicate=namespace:in_nether] 0 1 0`

It worked perfectly. All entities that traveled to the Nether were instantly teleported to Overworld 0x 1y 0z.

---

It seemed that `/tp` worked differently than `/spreadplayers`. So, my next attempt was to place the following commands into a function I called `portal`:

```
tp @s 0 1 0
spreadplayers 0 0 0 45 under 30 false @s
```

I ran this function every tick:

`execute as @e[predicate=namespace:in_nether] run function namespace:portal`

It worked- whenever my player traveled through the portal, it was instantly teleported to Overworld 0x 1y 0z and then spread randomly around Overworld 0x 0z. But then I found that it seemed to *only work for my player*.

When any other type of entity traveled to the Nether, they were teleported back to Overworld 0x 1y 0z, but not spread randomly.

---

I finally found a working solution: ([And it created a client-side visual glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEtAm.jpg))

```
tag @e[predicate=namespace:in_nether] add in_nether
tp @e[predicate=namespace:in_nether] 0 1 0
spreadplayers 0 0 0 45 under 30 false @e[tag=in_nether]
tag @e[tag=in_nether] remove in_nether
```

This solution is laggier and more complex than what I originally thought would work. I'm not sure why /spreadplayers acts this way, so to restate my question- What is the most efficient way to /spreadplayers into a different dimension? (And why did my other more elegant solutions not work?!) Thanks

Comment: This seems very long. Can you make it shorter?

Comment: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-181832

Answer (score 1):

Your idea may be the best you can do.

It seems like our friend Fabian Röling has pointed out a [bug report](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-181832) about this issue. Because it has been confirmed as a bug, it means that `/spreadplayers` should not act this way.

Therefore, to answer your original question, the theoretical most effective way to `/spreadplayers` into a different dimension is one of your original trials:

```
execute in minecraft:overworld run spreadplayers 0 0 0 45 under 30 false @e[predicate=namespace:in_nether]
```

But because of the bug, it doesn’t work. And you had to find a workaround.